# How to use NetApp SAN storage to provide Kubernetes Persistent Volumes?

Tags: kubernetes, storage

In our company, we utilize VMWare VSphere as our virtualization solution and a NetApp SAN for storage. The NetApp SAN is connected to VCenter, which is running in FC (Fibre Channel) mode. We have chosen not to support iSCSI or any TCP/IP bound protocol.

Currently, we have a production-ready Kubernetes cluster running on nodes from VCenter, which supports our stateless applications. However, we encountered a challenge when we wanted to migrate our stateful workloads (databases, object storages, etc.) to K8S. We are in need of a resilient solution to provide PersistentVolumes in our cluster, and we prefer not to use hostpath. Therefore, we require a CSI plugin that can provide dynamic volumes.

After exploring different options, it appears that the [NetApp's CSI plugin (Trident)](https://github.com/NetApp/trident) is not yet production-ready and does not support FC mode. This information is based on the documentation and [an issue raised on the Trident GitHub repository](https://github.com/NetApp/trident/issues/245).

There is a [CSI plugin compatible with FC SAN for Dell products](https://dell.github.io/csm-docs/docs/csidriver), but it seems to be specific to Dell.

Overall, we didn't find a proper way to connect the NetApp SAN directly to K8S and went for another solution and we reached [VMWare CNS (Cloud Native Storage) plugin for VSphere](https://github.com/vmware-samples/cloud-native-storage-self-service-manager), conceptually, it can do the job for us (in conjunction with VSphere CSI and/or VSphere CPI), but it seems that it only support vSAN as storage backend and not the SAN luns (I'm not sure, it was not clear enough in the docs).

I have two (or maybe three questions now):

1. Is there any CSI plugin for NetApp SAN FC mode to directly use it in K8S?
2. Is it possible to connect the CNS directly to SAN and to the VSphere CSI in K8S?
3. If the answer to neither of the above is yes, what can we do to provide K8S storages with our existing hardware?